# Can I use NHibernate SysCache with Non-Web-Application?

Tags: nhibernate, caching, nhibernate-3, syscache2, syscache

I have a Windows Service which is using NHibernate (3) and SQL Server 2008. WPF-Clients are connecting over WCF to this Service for using DataAccess.
My question is now: Can I use SysCache or SysCache2 in this Scenario - or are they only usable in Web-/ASP.NET-Applications?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Does NHibernate SysCache work in a non-web app?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2572441/does-nhibernate-syscache-work-in-a-non-web-app)

Comment: @ThomasC.G.deVilhena it *is* a duplicate, but the accepted answer to that question is wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it works just fine.

You can use it even in a console app if you want to (provided the computer has the full .NET Framework installed and not just the Client Profile).

Comment: I don't think this is correct. SysCache2 uses the ASP.NET cache which does nothing in a non-web environment.

Comment: @cbp that is just not true. You can use it without problems. Just try.

Comment: We now have SysCache3 which uses System.Runtime.Caching.

Comment: @cbp try harder, because I have apps in production that use it :-)